# Laravel unit-test failing, but working in 'real life'?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I'm working on a new app. Most of my unit-tests work as I expect them to, except one where I'm updating an existing item:

```
    /** @test */
    function can_edit_thought()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/submit', [
            'thought' => 'My first thought'
        ]);

        $thought_id = $user->thoughts->first()->id;

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->post('/submit', [
            'thought' => 'something different',
            'thought_id' => "1"
        ]);

        // should get redirected to 'thoughts'
        $response
            ->assertStatus(302)
            ->assertHeader('Location', url('/thoughts'));

        // should still be 1 thought...
        $this->assertEquals($user->thoughts->count(), 1);

        // the first thought should now containt "different"
        $thought = $user->thoughts->first();
        //fwrite(STDERR, print_r($user->thoughts, TRUE));
        $this->assertTrue(str_contains($thought->thought, "different"));
```

This last assert fails (and printing the 'thought' also shows it's not changed).

But when I do *exactly the same* in my app, the changes do happen.

Any ideas? (I'm leaning toward something with authentication, or the fact that test uses lite and real-app uses MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug, I needed to do a refresh:

```
        // the first thought should now containt "different"
        $thought = $user->thoughts->first();
        $thought->refresh();
        $this->assertTrue(str_contains($thought->thought, "different"));
```

(leaving this here for future bug hunters)